# Can late answers show if the question has a previously accepted answer?

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer, review

This is a useful page https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers, but: Can late answers show (display) if the question has a previously accepted answer?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for / suggesting here...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The list shows even if the question has previously accepted answers too.
Check this question which shows in the list of late answers -

[Waiting for the command to complete in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169910/waiting-for-the-command-to-complete-in-c/4943367#4943367)

Comment: I'm just wondering if it can mark the question in a specific way so we know at a glance whether its been resolved.